# Python dual logging based on an argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm trying to get logging to the file log as well to the console based on provided argument.

Code for that part looks like:

```
logFormatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-5.5s]  %(message)s")
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

fileHandler = logging.FileHandler("{0}/{1}.log".format(logPath, fileName), mode='a')
fileHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
_logger.addHandler(fileHandler)

def parse_args(args):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="My Script")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-v",
        "--verbose",
        dest="loglevel",
        help="set loglevel to INFO",
        action="store_const",
        const=logging.INFO)
    parser.add_argument(
        "-vv",
        "--very-verbose",
        dest="loglevel",
        help="set loglevel to DEBUG",
        action="store_const",
        const=logging.DEBUG)
    return parser.parse_args(args)

def setup_logging(loglevel):
    logformat = "%(asctime)s [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-5.5s]  %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(level=loglevel, stream=sys.stdout, format=logformat, datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

def main(args):
    args = parse_args(args)
    setup_logging(args.loglevel)
    _logger.info("Script starts here")
    """main code"""
    _logger.info("Script ends here")

def run():
    """Entry point for console_scripts
    """
    main(sys.argv[1:])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

it will works fine when I run script with `-v` or `-vv` argument but when is not provider log file is not created either when I expect to have all logs saved there at any time.

How can I have it specified that log file will be created each time and `stdout` only on verbose request?

PS.
I have moved some code to

```
def setup_logging(loglevel):
    logFormatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-5.5s]  %(message)s")

    if loglevel is not None:
        logformat = "%(asctime)s [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-5.5s]  %(message)s"
        logging.basicConfig(level=loglevel, stream=sys.stdout, format=logformat, datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    _logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fileHandler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler("{0}/{1}.log".format(logPath, logFileName), when="midnight")
    fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
    _logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
```

that will log to the log file all the time and then output on verbose but log file is saving only output logging set as `INFO` nothing which comes as `DEBUG` as can be seen when running as verbose `-vv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it fixed by updating `setup_logging()`:

```
_logger = logging.getLogger()
http_client_logger = logging.getLogger("http.client")

def print_to_log(*args):
    http_client_logger.debug(" ".join(args))


def setup_logging(loglevel, logPath, logFile):
    fileHandler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler("{0}/{1}.log".format(logPath, logFile), when="midnight")
    fileHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    handlers = [fileHandler]

    if loglevel is not None:
        # if a log level is configured, use that for logging to the console
        stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        stream_handler.setLevel(loglevel)
        handlers.append(stream_handler)

    if loglevel == logging.DEBUG:
        # when logging at debug level, make http.client extra chatty too
        http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

    logformat = "%(asctime)s [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-5.5s]  %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(format=logformat, datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", handlers=handlers, level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a default value for loglevel when no option is provided.

```
parser.add_argument(
    "-v",
    "--verbose",
    dest="loglevel",
    help="set loglevel to INFO",
    action="store_const",
    default=logging.DEBUG, # <---- You are missing this line here
    const=logging.INFO)
```

Comment: I had something like that before and that will display logs in the console without passing `-v`

Comment: I have added more to the OP. I'm close to what I'm looking for but not getting correct log level output