# python3.7 requests: logging to a file: Does not log everything

Tags: python, logging

I am using

```
$ python --version                                                                                                                                                                      
Python 3.7.3
```

I am trying the following code to log the output of request to a file

```
import requests
import logging

import http.client as http_client
http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

# You must initialize logging, otherwise you'll not see debug output.
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True

handler = logging.FileHandler('test2.log',mode='a')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  

requests_log.addHandler(handler)

requests.get('https://httpbin.org/headers')
```

What i see in the `test2.log` is

```
2021-03-07 17:50:22,312 - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): httpbin.org:443
2021-03-07 17:50:22,376 - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - https://httpbin.org:443 "GET /headers HTTP/1.1" 200 225
```

Why am I not able to see the other output which shows in the console in the log, i.e as below

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): httpbin.org:443
send: b'GET /headers HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: httpbin.org\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.24.0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Date: Sun, 07 Mar 2021 12:20:21 GMT
header: Content-Type: application/json
header: Content-Length: 225
header: Connection: keep-alive
header: Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
header: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://httpbin.org:443 "GET /headers HTTP/1.1" 200 225
```

HOw to get the headers data also into the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to monkey-patch the print function of `http.client` module? Unfortunately, it uses prints instead of Python logging module, hence this behaviour.

Adding add the following piece of code before your request should work:

```
def print_to_log(*args):
    requests_log.debug(" ".join(args)) 
http_client.print = print_to_log
```

*Related answers ([Log all requests from the python-requests module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337511/log-all-requests-from-the-python-requests-module) and [Python HTTP request and debug level logging to the log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58738195/python-http-request-and-debug-level-logging-to-the-log-file)).*

Comment: And it would seem it is still this way in latest Python versions as of 2021 https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/8633

Comment: how to monkey patch

Comment: The piece of code above is what's called the monkey patch. You just need to put it in files where you import the http.client module